# jQuery Data Table - Show Details Row is not working post data update

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, jquery-plugins

**Issue:**
Referring the following link for jQuery DataTable, works perfectly onclick of + icon (i.e. row details are shown) but when the data is updated 2nd time it does not work thereafter.

**Main Condition:**

```
if (row.child.isShown()) {
...
} else {
...
}
```

The tutorial I'm following can be found [here](https://datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html).

My Observation - I found that when i refresh data 2nd time and click on + icon, it is executing both if & else condition strangely. I.e. it is showing the row and immediately hiding the row.

The 3rd time when i refresh data and click on + icon, it works prefectly onclick of + icon, executing if-else-if (all 3 in console.log),

When i refresh data 4th time and click on + icon, it does not work, following execution if-else-if-else (4 times under log).

```
var detailRows = [];
$('#alertTable tbody').on('click', 'tr td.details-control', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    table = $('#alertTable').DataTable();
    var row = table.row(tr);
    var idx = $.inArray(tr.attr('id'), detailRows);
    if (row.child.isShown()) {
        console.log('True...');
        tr.removeClass('details');
        row.child.hide();
        detailRows.splice(idx, 1);
    } else {
        console.log('False...');
        tr.addClass('details');
        row.child(format(row.data())).show();
        if (idx === -1) {
            detailRows.push(tr.attr('id'));
        }
    }
});
table.on('draw', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.each(detailRows, function (i, id) {
        $('#' + id + ' td.details-control').trigger('click');
    });
});
```

Only Odd data refreshes are working. Any help shall be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you need to remove class shown and later add it, since your isShow logic is based on that tr.removeClass('shown'); and tr.addClass('shown'); you can see more here https://datatables.net/reference/api/row().child.isShown()

Comment: Can you please update the above code?

Comment: replace tr.addClass('details'); with tr.addClass('shown'); and tr.removeClass('details'); with  tr.removeClass('shown'); under console.log

Comment: Thanks but it does not work using the above said. Tried clearing cache, but still the same.